# Recvfrom windows function doesn’t receive all packets from the OS

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock, recvfrom

I wrote a c++ windows process (Win7 if it matters) that can send and receive packets using `sendto` and `recvfrom`, but unfortunately not all of the packets are read from the socket. Both of the computers are directly connected and transmitting bi-directionally 2000 packets (1 packet per second, 500bit each), when I open WireShark I can see that the 2000 packets got to the destination but for some reason my process reads from the socket less than 2000 (~1980 packets).  The `recvfrom` function is in a task that runs as long as the process is alive.
What could be the reason that the packet gets to the destination but my process didn't receive it? Is there a problem with my code or a known problem with recvfrom or maybe is it because it's udp?
There are no errors involved, this is part of the code:

Update: the problem was with the socket configuration. When i opened it i used setsockopt SO_RCVTIMO of 1 second, changed 1 to 100000 microsecond and it fixed the problem.

```
    socklen_t sockaddr_in_len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);  
    nResult = recvfrom(s,
                              buff,
                              buffLen,
                              0,
                              (sockaddr*)sender,
                              &sockaddr_in_len);  
        SAFE_UINT ulError = WSAGetLastError();



        if (nResult == -1)  


{  
    if(ulError != WSAETIMEDOUT)  
        {   
            Sleep(100);  
            switch (ulError)  
            {  
                case WSAECONNRESET:  
                    //Print error     
                    return S_OK;  
                case WSAEINTR:  
                    //Print error  
                    return S_OK;  
                case WSAENOTSOCK:  
    //Print error  
                    return S_OK;   
                case WSAENOTCONN:  
                    //Print error  
                    return S_OK;   
                default:  
                    //Print error  
                    return S_OK;   
            }  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            //Print error  
            return S_OK;   
        }  
    }  
    else if (nResult == 0)  
    {  
        //Print error  
        return S_OK;  
    }
```

Comment: Since you use `recvfrom` I assume you're using UDP?

Comment: I don't see a loop round `recvfrom`.  `recvfrom` can receive partial/split packets and you need to reassemble them before passing the whole packet(s) up to your next layer.  You need to check the value in `nResult`  to determine now much `recvfrom` actually received.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's only a problem with TCP. With UDP you receive a full packet (possibly delayed and out of order) or you don't.

Comment: It’s indeed UDP and I do use a loop, I just didn’t copy it :) as I explained, 1980 out of the 2000 packets are read (sometimes less and sometimes 2000/2000).

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that your process will receive a UDP datagram just because it reached the machine.

Comment: @molbdnilo What do you mean?

Comment: Why are you using `Sleep(100)`?  Please show the complete loop containing the `recvfrom` call.

Comment: As you should know, UDP is a protocol without any delivery guarantees. Packets can and will get lost. Exactly when and where that happens doesn't matter. It might be in a router between the two hosts, or it might be inside the local computer between the hardware interface and your program.

Comment: The loop is a while(true) loop. The missing packets are usually after a few hundreds and none of the errors appear. Do you think maybe I’m missing something?  maybe nResult>0 but “unreadable” for some reason?

Comment: @Shani.M UDP does not guarantee delivery. If you want guarantees, you need to implement your own protocol on top of UDP, or switch to TCP/IP and implement a packet protocol on top of that.

Comment: Please state your question as a question - it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Danny Varod My question is what could be the reason that the packet gets to the destination but my process didn't receive it? Is there a problem with my code or a known problem with recvfrom or maybe is it because it's udp?

Comment: Then edit the question, don't write this as a comment.

Comment: Why are you treating a timeout as a success?